# How to invoke web services on WSDL URL in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, playframework-2.0

I need to invoke some web service methods within a java web application that I'm building.

E.g each time a user signs up, I want to call the `newUser` method on a WSDL url via Java. I'd need to pass on some parameters with the request.

Is there any built in Java class, or any publicly available class, which can make this easy, i.e I just supply the URL and the parameters, and it performs the request and returns the response?

If not, what is the standard way of invoking web services on WSDL in Java applications?

Comment: You can make a POST request using the Apache Commons HTTP client.  SOAP services speak HTTP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run wsimport on the deployed WSDL URL , you can run it from your JDK:

```
wsimport -p client -keep http://localhost:8080/calculator?wsdl
```

This step will generates and compile some classes. Notice -keep switch, you need it to keep the generated Java source files.

Calculator.java - Service Endpoint Interface or SEI
CalculatorService - Generated Service, instantiate it

```
public class MyClientServiceImpl {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    @Override
    public Integer add(int a , int b) {
       CalculatorService service = new CalculatorService();
       Calculator calculatorProxy = service.getCalculatorPort();            
        /**
         * Invoke the remote method
         */
        int result = calculatorProxy.add(10, 20);
        System.out.println("Sum of 10+20 = "+result);
    }
}
```

If you are using the Java EE 6 supported container then you can use it in this way ,

```
public class MyClientServiceImpl implements MyClientService {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/calculator?wsdl", 
value = CalculatorService.class)
    private Calculator service;

    @Override
    public Integer add(int a , int b) {
        return service.add(a,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I install / run WSImport? I'm on Linux.

Comment: Run $ which java on your linux , You need launch it from your JDK directory in linux , http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Comment: Thanks, its working now. Can you please delete the comments where you included the URLs? And then I'll accept.

Comment: I have removed the comments with WSDL url