# Package org.apache.axis.client does not exist Play Framework

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, apache-axis

I'm new to play framework, using Idea IDE, coding in java and I've bumped into error which I can't manage. I'm trying to generate proxi classes from wsdl and then use them in my play project.

My procedure is (from blank project):

- Right-click my project > new > new module
- java module > webservices client - filled with:
  on - generate sample client code
  version - apache axis
  libraries - dowload
- generate java code from wsdl
  web service wsdl - url http:// ....SelfCareService.svc?wsdl
  output path - project/app
  everything else on default
- everything is generated

Then I check localhost:9000 and what I get is:

> Compilation error
>   error: package org.apache.axis.client does not exist
>   In path\project\app\mypackage\BasicHttpBinding_ISelfCareServiceStub.java at line 10.

`package mypackage;

public class BasicHttpBinding_ISelfCareServiceStub extends org.apache.axis.client.Stub implements mypackage.ISelfCareService {

private java.util.Vector cachedSerClasses = new java.util.Vector();

private java.util.Vector cachedSerQNames = new java.util.Vector();

private java.util.Vector cachedSerFactories = new java.util.Vector();

private java.util.Vector cachedDeserFactories = new java.util.Vector();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you include the apache jar in your project? In Playframework, there are two ways of handling this :

1. Used managed dependencies in your `build.scala` file and as shown in [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTDependencies).
2. Unmanaged dependencies, add the requested jar into the `lib` folder at the root of your project (create it if it doesn't exist)

Then reload your application and it should run ok.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I succeded solving the problem with this piece of advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187385/how-to-invoke-web-services-on-wsdl-url-in-java