# Calling a WSDL method from an URL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

@Disclaimer: None of our crew is an expert in Java or webservices, therefore we avoided complex solutions until now. At this point, we are up to anything you guys suggest, keeping in mind that we can't afford to rewrite the entire server.

So, basically, I have a webservice made in Java...
We also have some WSDL classes ready for use. Those classes work and the server is fully functional.

But, now, we have to be able to access the WSDL methos using an URL.
We tried declaring @WebMethods and accessing it through normal means (http://localhost:8080/MyWSDL/Method) but we didn't manage to make it work.

We are kinda desperate right now, since we have a major problem going on and that would be the most time efficient solution.

We are relying on the eclipse code generator to make the transition from java classes to WSDL. Also, we are using Axis 1.4, Tomcat 7.0 and Eclipse Luna.

In advance, thank you for your patience and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Spring makes this trivial, you might wanna take a look at it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke web services on WSDL URL in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187385/how-to-invoke-web-services-on-wsdl-url-in-java)

Comment: Ill take a look at Spring and see if we can adapt to fit into our project. Thank you!
In the mean time, is there anything we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

IMO...Sounds like you have a restful endpoint. Ditch the WSDL idea. I would suggest looking at making a rest call thru a Poster. Given more info about Params and actually seeing the method, might be able to help you get a successful call? Help us, help you! Good luck!

Note...SOAP requires an XSD handshake, more difficult to call from a webpage. SOAP is usually reserved for server to server webservices.